# XDomainRequest to different server with different protocol

Tags: http, https, xdomainrequest

I'm currently writing a script which is purposefully leaving out jquery as a dependency.

So with Native JS I am making a CORS request to a server. However, I can't control the protocol of the browser. Some may be http:, some may be https:. The server I post to will always be https: How do I with the native XDomainRequest object in IE 8 and 9 allow posting to these even if the location.protocol is different than the requested domains protocol?

Comment: XDomainRequest can't do this. You could use a form post instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work for the setup I'm doing. The script I'm writing will be injected on many different pages, which I have no control over. How does jQuery AJAX make CORS requests in old browsers? There has to be a way.

Comment: You could also use JSON-P. This is what "crossdomain" means to JQUery before CORS arrived.